# Выравнивание текста к низу в блоках

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Как выровнять текст в блоках на одном уровне, при том чтобы картинки оставались своего размера (разной высоты и ширины). Желательно решение на flexbox

```css
.materials {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.materials .item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="materials">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-z_gfgLD-hs2nhagIKxyPMS1MeUKCDpzcVVGaQSQmaClSG-lcFg" alt="">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor labore animi autem.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/J5VOkREA-e0pn7uHn1Fw80xeuXwc4hTEYH2fsOw_dY1cTUkfMHPql5wRa7gy-LjjwUM=w300" alt="">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor labore animi autem.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.materials {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.materials .item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="materials">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-z_gfgLD-hs2nhagIKxyPMS1MeUKCDpzcVVGaQSQmaClSG-lcFg" alt="">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor labore animi autem.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/J5VOkREA-e0pn7uHn1Fw80xeuXwc4hTEYH2fsOw_dY1cTUkfMHPql5wRa7gy-LjjwUM=w300" alt="">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor labore animi autem.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```